# ID for Contact portion of Person Account

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to get the ID of a Contact which is part of a Person Account?

I have a custom object which has a custom field referencing the Person Account, though it seems to be referencing the Contact directly. I have created a button which I am using to pass the ID into a Visualforce Page.

With the Insert Field drop-down on the create/edit button page I can put in `{!Account.Id}` or `{!Contact.Id}` but neither of these work. The Account ID is placed in the URL but is not the correct ID and the Contact ID is blank, which I assume is because the button is on a Person Account page and not a Contact Page.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing the answer to this too. I recall trawling through the Force.com ID schema browser in the past looking for it, but was unable to find it.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on what isn't working?  We have custom objects referencing Person Accounts by doing lookups to Accounts, filtered by "Is Person Account" and record types.  I haven't tried linking our PAs to Visualforce pages yet, though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I Up-voted Mike Chale as he pointed me in the right direction.

To get this to work I use the `Account.Id` to get the `Account.PersonContactId` which is then used in my Custom Object.

```
Account a = [Select PersonContactId From Account Where Id = :AccountId];
CustomObject co = [Select Name From CustomObject Where Client__c = :a.PersonContactId];
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to get this value in the Merge Field drop-down list on the create/edit button page.

A list of all person account fields can be found in the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm#topic-title). Scroll 2/3 down the page to the section titled "IsPersonAccount Fields".

Comment: Could you populate that into a custom field, maybe via trigger when a new PA is created?

Comment: You would probably have to do it after the insert so the `Id` exists, but I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Using the Schema Builder, I see the Account object has a "Person Contact" field, that is a Lookup(Contact).  That is the only filed I see that seems to reference Person Accounts.

Edit: Double-clicking on that field shows the field name to "Person_Contact".

Comment: Do you know the API name of this field? I think that's what needed for @Nalum's merge fields.

Comment: All it shows is the field name being "Person_Contact".

Comment: This does not exist in the merge fields. Tough I may be able to use it in the Apex code. Will check that now.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue accessing this field, I solved it by creating a formula field on the account object to show it - the formula was simply PersonContact.Id